# javaで画面共有を行うライブラリについて(スクリーンショット以外の方法)

Tags: java

現在、Javaでvncのような画面共有ソフトを開発したいと考えています
パソコンをモニターにつなぐとモニターの大小関係なくきれいに表示されると思いますが小さいモニターで撮ったスクリーンショットを大きなモニターで大画面で表示しようとすると荒く表示されると思います。
スクリーンショットとは別の方法でOSから出力される画面の情報を入手しモニターの大小関係なくきれいに表示したいです。Javaのライブラリやgithubなどを見ましたがまだ調べる能力が足りずこの問題を解決する方法を得ることはできませんでした。どこに自分が必要としている情報があるのかわかりません。
vncなどはこれをどうやって解決しているのでしょうか
この問題を解決するJavaのライブラリはあるのでしょうか
回答よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

本家のstackoverflowに関連しそうな質問がありました。

[Java VNC Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66504/java-vnc-libraries)

この回答にあるように、[Download TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.html)の`TightVNC source code`にC++ですがサーバー側のソースがあり、
同様に、`TightVNC Java Viewer source code`にJavaのビューア(クライアント)側のソースがあります。

これらのソースが参考になると思います。